# HTML Page trying to get information from php / mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

This fairly simple issue is vexing me.  I have an html page laid out with CSS.  I have a simple php page that returns the latest record from a mysql site.  I need to display this information in the html page in the "leftContent" div.

working 'latest.php' page is:

```
<?php
/* 
Return the latest date and record for the left pane.
*/

include 'ESP8266_dbLogin.php';

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `thLog` ORDER BY logID DESC LIMIT 1") or die ("Connection error");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "Date: " . $row['logDate'] . "<br>";
echo "lightVal: " . $row['lightVal'];
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

'index.html' code is as follows, with the target DIV of contentLeft for the php variables:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Basic Layout -->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Sparks - Monitor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/default.css">
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="data24.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="banner">
        <div id="bannerLeft">
          <img class="bannerImg" alt="ESP8266 Logo" src="images\imgESP8266.png">
        </div>
        <div id="bannerRight">
          <img class="bannerImg" alt="Settings Icon" src="images\imgGear.png">
        </div>
        <div id="bannerMain">
          <h1>SPARKS Energy Monitor - Home</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="contentLeft">
        <h2>Current Usage:</h2>
        <p> The current lightVal and date should be here<p>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="contentRight">
        Generating chart, please wait...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  </body>
<html>
```

Any help is gratefully received on the most efficient way to get the php variables (lightVal) into the html page.  I know, stupid question!!

Comment: Actually the best option would be for you to start using Twig for templating. Or, if you want to roll your own templating system: [read this](http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html).

Answer (score 0):

1) Rename your `index.html` to `index.php`
2) Replace your target `div` with your PHP code:

```
  <div class="content" id="contentLeft">
    <h2>Current Usage:</h2>
    <?php
        /* 
        Return the latest date and record for the left pane.
        */
        include 'ESP8266_dbLogin.php';

        $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `thLog` ORDER BY logID DESC LIMIT 1") or die ("Connection error");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
      <p class="dateClass"><?=$row['logDate']?></p>
      <p class="lightValClass"><?=$row['lightVal']?></p>
    <?
        }
        mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
  </div>
```

It should be enough, just call index.php from browser.

Comment: This works well.  How do I format it with my separate default.css file?  Thanks.